# How to list poetry plugins in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I've added a poetry plugin manually with `poetry self add xxx`, but I don't see any line changed in the pyproject.toml or poetry.lock. I want this plugin to be included in the development environment, so it needs to install when others set-up the environment. Can you add plugins to the `--dev` dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible (Poetry version 1.6.1). There is [a related issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7657) in Poetry's repository from earlier this year, but it hasn't been implemented.